# Missing Gemfile when using Docker on Heroku

Tags: heroku, docker, rubygems

I am trying out the docker plugin for Heroku, just locally to start with. When I run `docker-compose up web` I get the following error:

```
Building web
Step 1 : FROM heroku/ruby
# Executing 7 build triggers...
Step 1 : COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /app/user/
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: lstat Gemfile: no such file or directory
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: 'bash -c ''bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb'''
  working_dir: /app/user
  environment:
    PORT: 8080
    DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://postgres:@herokuPostgresql:5432/postgres'
  ports:
    - '8080:8080'
  links:
    - herokuPostgresql
shell:
  build: .
  command: bash
  working_dir: /app/user
  environment:
    PORT: 8080
    DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://postgres:@herokuPostgresql:5432/postgres'
  ports:
    - '8080:8080'
  links:
    - herokuPostgresql
  volumes:
    - '.:/app/user'
herokuPostgresql:
  image: postgres
```

Why is the Gemfile missing, but most importantly how should it look like for my docker?

Comment: Please provide your `Dockerfile` for the `web`